# Get list of all twig templates Symfony

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, symfony-2.8

I search for a method to get the list of all twig templates in my Symfony2 project.
I hope to get a result like this :

```
- AcmeBundle:Default:list.html.twig 
- OtherBundle:ParentFolder:new.html.twig
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: hi you can use Finder to Search file that have twig extension

Comment: I have already tried but it does not give me the desired result.

Comment: Pretty sure there is no master list.  You could look at the "compiled" twig files under var/cache/env//twig.  The first comment in each file looks like: /* @WebProfiler/Collector/config.html.twig */

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi You can try this Code But you will need to adjust it

```
    $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');
    $bundles = $kernel->getBundles();
    $res = array();
    foreach ($bundles as $key => $value) {
        $path = $kernel->locateResource("@$key");
        $array = explode('\\', $path);
        if (in_array('vendor', $array))
            continue;
        $finder = new Finder();
        $finder->in($path);
        $finder->files()->name('*.twig');
        foreach ($finder as $val) {
            $explodurl = explode('Resources\views\\', $val->getPathname());
            $string = end($explodurl);
            $string = str_replace("\\", ':', $string);
            $res[] = "$key:$string";
        }
    }
     dump($res);
```

Comment: Thanks , great function

Answer (score 1):

To use it in unix ( nginx )

```
 $res = array();
    foreach ($this->getBundles() as $key => $value) {
        $keyAlias = $value->getName();
        $path = $kernel->locateResource("@$keyAlias");
        $array = explode('//', $path);
        if (in_array('vendor', $array))
            continue;
        $finder = new Finder();
        $finder->in($path);
        $finder->files()->name('*.twig');
        foreach ($finder as $val) {
            $explodurl = explode('//Resources/views/', $val->getPathname());
            $string = end($explodurl);
            $string = str_replace("/", ':', $string);
            $res[] = "$keyAlias:$string";
        }
    }
   dump($res);

private function getBundles() {
    $kernel = $this->getContainer()->get('kernel');
    $bundles = [];
    $allBundles = $kernel->getBundles();
    foreach ($allBundles as $bundle) {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($bundle);
        $bundleDirectory = dirname($reflection->getFileName());
        if (!preg_match("/vendor/i", $bundleDirectory, $matches)) {
            $bundles[] = $bundle;
        }
    }
    return $bundles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the getLoaderPaths found at

https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge/blob/master/Command/DebugCommand.php

or just use

$loader = $this->twig->getLoader();

as loader will contain a list of paths